# SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Account.Wholesaler__r:

Tags: trigger, after

I have a custom object lookup Wholesaler__c in Account Object. my requirement is to create a trigger, which would create a custom object record Billing__c when an Opportunity is created. Billing__c should take inputs from Opportunity

error thrown is:

> "Apex trigger CreateBilling caused an unexpected exception, contact
>   your administrator: CreateBilling: execution of AfterInsert caused by:
>   System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without
>   querying the requested field: Account.Wholesaler__r:
>   Trigger.CreateBilling: line 12, column 1"

please help

Trigger written is:

```
trigger CreateBilling on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
    billing__c bill = new billing__c();

    if(Trigger.isInsert == true){
        for(Opportunity opp: Trigger.new){
            if(Opp.StageName == 'Closed Won'){
                bill.Name='bill ' +opp.Name;
                bill.Opportunity__c=opp.id;
                bill.Dealer__c= opp.AccountId;
              //  Id accid =opp.AccountId;
                wholesaler__c wholesalerName = new wholesaler__c();
                wholesalerName= [SELECT Account.Wholesaler__c FROM account where id =:opp.AccountId].wholesaler__r;
                bill.Wholesaler__c= wholesalerName.name;
                system.debug('No errors observed with billing addition');
                insert bill;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: update  your query `[SELECT Name, wholesaler__c, Account.Wholesaler__c FROM account where id =:opp.AccountId].wholesaler__c`

Comment: @arun Did you understand why you were facing this error?

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty: i thought i understood. so modified my query. but eventhen i couldnt resolve the issue. so i guess, my understanding is wrong

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Comment: @CasparHarmer: this query worked. however, please help me understand, why are we fetching wholesaler__c and assigning it to account[] ? why cant it be wholesaler ?

Comment: When you run a select, you are retrieving a list of (in this case) Account objects with the Wholesaler__c field on it. This field is actually an id. So we now have the id, which we can put on the Bill__c. We never need to retrieve the `Wholesaler__c` OBJECT (which is, unfortunately in saleforce syntax, named the same thing) - Also note, I've put instructions on how to bulkify the trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have SOQL in a for loop - which is something you will need to fix.

Aside from that, I think you are trying to get the wholesaler id and put it on the bill. For that, you don't need wholesaler name, just the `wholesaler__c` field on Account.
Try this:

```
Account[] accts = [SELECT Account.Wholesaler__c FROM account where id =:opp.AccountId]
bill.Wholesaler__c= accts[0].Wholesaler__c;
```

The above can replace these three lines:

```
wholesaler__c wholesalerName = new wholesaler__c();
wholesalerName= [SELECT Account.Wholesaler__c FROM account where id =:opp.AccountId].wholesaler__r;
bill.Wholesaler__c= wholesalerName.name;
```

Going back to the SOQL in the for loop, to remove this (a process called bulkifying the trigger), you would:

- Loop through all the Opportunities and collect all the account ids in a set.
- Query all Accounts in this set into a list.
- Put each Account into a map, indexed by Opportunity id.
- Loop through the Opportunities again, creating bill records.
- Get the indexed Account for each Opportunity and put the wholesaler name on the `Bill__c`.
- Add each newly created `Bill__c` to a `List<Bill__c>` of bills.

Finally insert these new bills.

Answer (score 2):

There were so many issues with your code

- SOQL Query inside for loop
- DML Statement inside for loop
- You code was not bulkified for queries
- You were initialising your bill variable at the second line, it will use the same bill reference if multiple opportunities are updated together, resulting in an error.
- I don't know why you were initialising a wholesale object, when you can directly query the name

Compare your code with this below optimised code:

```
trigger CreateBilling on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {

    Billing__c bill;
    List<Billing__c> billingList = new List<Billing__c>();
    Set<id> accntSet = new Set<id>();
    Map<ID,String> wholesalerMap = new Map<ID,String>();

    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        for(Opportunity opp: Trigger.new){
            if(Opp.StageName == 'Closed Won'){
                accntSet.add(opp.AccountId);
            }
        }
        for(Account acc : [SELECT Wholesaler__r.Name FROM account where id =:accntSet Limit :accntSet.size()])
            wholesalerMap.put(acc.id, acc.Wholesaler__r.Name);

        for(Opportunity opp: Trigger.new){
            if(Opp.StageName == 'Closed Won'){
                bill = new billing__c();
                bill.Name='bill ' +opp.Name;
                bill.Opportunity__c=opp.id;
                bill.Dealer__c= opp.AccountId;

                bill.Wholesaler__c= wholesalerMap.get(opp.AccountId);
                billingList.add(bill);
            }
        }

        if(!billingList.isEmpty())
            insert billingList;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps to answer your question.